# 2D Int Array print using pointers

Tags: c

While executing the below code:

```
int main()
{
  int abc[3][3]={0};
  for(int *ip=&abc[0][0];ip<=&abc[3][3];ip++)
  {
    printf("%d   \n",*ip);
  }
}
```

Expected result is 9 zeros but it displays 12 data.  What might be reason?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the memory layout of a 3x3 array, it looks like:

```
[0][0]          [1][0]        [2][0]         
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Where is the element `[3][3]`?

```
[0][0]          [1][0]        [2][0]         [3][0]         [3][3] 
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

That explains why you end up accessing 12 elements.

Your code is subject to undefined behavior for accessing the beyond valid indices but that's another issue.

You could use:

```
for (int *ip = &abc[0][0]; ip <= &abc[2][2]; ip++)
{
  printf("%d   \n",*ip);
}
```

However, it is  better to access a 2D array as a 2D array.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i )
{
  for (size_t j = 0; j < 3; ++j )
  {
    printf("%d   \n", abc[i][j]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes Its right. While printing last 3 values shows junk values instead zero.

Comment: @alk, `<=`  is right. `abc[2][2]` is a valid element.